# Is there any difference between weapons in Cursed Crusade?

Tags: cursed-crusade

I've been watching LoadingReadyRun's playthrough of Cursed Crusade, and they can't tell any difference between the weapons they are constantly picking up, for example a 'Balanced Mace' vs a 'Barbarian Mace' or a 'Long Gladius' vs a 'Ceremonial Sword'. I've tried the usual google search terms, but can't seem to find a list of weapons. Are they all just renames of the same stats, or is there actually a difference in terms of effectiveness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It seems as though they have different effectiveness. Check out this guide for a detailed weapons list and effectiveness</strike>

http://vgfaq.com/guides/the-cursed-crusade-game-guide-finishing-moves-fighting-techniques-and-weapons-list/

NOTE: These moves have been extracted from the game, while playing on Xbox 360. Because of this, PlayStation 3 owners must replace all keys, as follows:

```
X (on Xbox 360) = Square (on PS3)
Y (on Xbox 360) = Triangle (on PS3)
A (on Xbox 360) = X (on PS3)
B (on Xbox 360) = Circle (on PS3)

Two-Handed Sword Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Great Blade - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Precision Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Chalice Breaker - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X
Blood Rain - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y
Body Wrack - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y, Y
Entrails Flayer - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Impaler - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y
Headhunter - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y, X
Lethal Feint - Medium Attack – Press: X, X
Flat of the Blade -Press: X, X, , B
Pommel Shock -¨Press: B
Vertical Great Blade - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Stone Scraper - Light Attack – Press: Y, X
Iron Sharp Edge - Light Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Heavy Dagger - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, X, Y
Noble’s Strike - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y
Moonless Night - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Greave Shredder - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X
Grim Reaper - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X, Y
Bereavement - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X, Y, Y
Sucker Punch - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Calculated Bow - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X
Vengeance - Press: Y, Y, Y, X, B
Hero’s Death - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y
Black Widow - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X
Anathema - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X, Y

One-Handed Sword Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Horizontal Blade - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Iron Backhand - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Whirling Death - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Fatal Slice - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Heartbreak - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Cutting Stroke - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y
Hilt Bash - Press: X, X, X, B
Shoulder Slice - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Brutal Pommel - Press: X, X, B
Long Pierce - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y
Debilitator - Light Attack – Press: X, Y, X
Secret of Steel - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, X, Y
Vertical Blade - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Quick Backhand - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X
Reaper - Light Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Leaping Strike - Press: Y, X, B
Vertical Backhand - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Heavy Slice - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Throat Slash - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X
Scar Maker - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, Y
Rising Kick - Press: Y, Y, B
Brutal Kick - Press: B

One-Handed Axe Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Axe Cleave - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Strong Backhand - Medium Attack – Press: X, X
Mercy Strike - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X
Wood Cleaver - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Armageddon - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Slaughterer - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Trunk Slicer - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y, X
Stone Rend - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y, X, Y
Woodsman Strike - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y
Marauder Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y, Y
Vicious Fang - Light Attack – Press: X, Y, Y, Y
Vertical Cleave - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Decapitator - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X
Artery Slice - Light Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Blood Bath - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X, X, Y
Valiant Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Tendon Cleaver - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Disemboweler - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X
Bark Flyer - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X, X
Flash Shredder - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y
Sepulture - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X
Knob Bash - Press: B

Mace Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Mace Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Teeth Breaker - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Knee Breaker - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X
Stone Splitter - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Trephining - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Lead Backhand - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Bone Duster - Press: X, X, B
Grinding Strike - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y
High Backhand - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, X
Stunning Bash - Press: B
Vertical Mace Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Greave Bucker - Light Attack – Press: Y, X
Skull Crusher - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Lower Strike - Light Attack – Press: Y, X, X, X
Iron Twister - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, Y
Ankle Taker - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, Y, X
Boot Breaker - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y
Dark Ascension - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Implacable - Press: Y, Y, Y, B

Double Sword Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Dual Blades - Medium Attack – Press: X
Double Cut - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Mass Grave - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Razor Waltz - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Cavity Pierce - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Martydrom - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y, Y
Grand Cross - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y
Dire Shear - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y, Y
Furious Rush - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Sepulchral Lay - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y
Pass of Arms - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y
Meat Cleaver - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, Y
Resounding Blow - Press: X, Y, B
Vertical Blades - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Double Slash - Light Attack – Press: Y, X
Parallel Slice - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Cruel Joust - Press: Y, X, X, B
Heavy Impact - Press: Y, X, B
Dual Backhand - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y
Blood Moon - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Madman’s Flay - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X
Heavy Cut - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Heart Burst - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y
Blood Cross - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X
Requiem - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X, Y
Guard’s Charge - Press: B

Double Axe Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Dual Axes - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Double Backhand - Medium Attack – Press: X, X
Paunch Ripper - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X
Stone Shearer - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Torment - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Salvation - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y, X
Wheeling Nail - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y
Macabre Lay - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y, Y
Malediction - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y, Y, Y
Implacable Leap - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Steel Fountain - Heavy Attack – Press: X,Y
Funeral Dirge - Heavy Attack – Press: X,Y,Y
Lethal Volte - Medium Attack – Press: X,Y,Y, X
Blinding Strike - Press: X,Y, B
Vertical Axes - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Twin Cut - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Double Scar - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Strappado - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X
Flesh Notch - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, Y
Soul Rend - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, Y, X
Dark Virelai - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, Y, Y
Parallel Furrows - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Justified Pain - Press: Y, Y, B
Iron Fists - Press: B

Sword and Shield Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Shielded Blade - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Metal Squall - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Triple Slash - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X
Twisting Ruin - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Fatal Coda - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Glorious Charge - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y
Metal Assault - Press: X, X, X, B
Heroic Charge - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Frontal Assault - Press: X, X, B
Brutal Extension - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y
Low Strike - Light Attack – Press: X, Y, X
Castrate’s Lay - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, X, Y
Thrusting Blade - Medium Attack – Press: Y
King’s Rampart - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X
Bestial Fang - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Shield Bash - Press: Y, X, B
Hero’s Valor - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y
Cross Slash - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Iron Lightning - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X
Sacrifice - Press: Y, Y, Y, X, B
Stone Club - Press: Y, Y, B
Shield Rush - Press: B

Axe and Shield Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Shielded Axe Cleave - Medium Attack – Press: X
Inferno Axe - Medium Attack – Press: X, X
Stained Blade - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X
Wing Slash - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Nightmare - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Absolution - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y, Y
Mercy’s End - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y
Veiled Virtue - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, Y, X
Bloody Gash - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Heavy Slash - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y, X
Blind Terror - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y, X, Y
Bloody Horizon - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y
Defiler - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y, Y
Saw Mill - Light Attack – Press: X, Y, Y, Y
Thrusting Axe - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Violent Quarrel - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Sever Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Black Rider - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X, X
Crusader Wrath - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X
Red Harvest - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y
Iron Maiden - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X
Sanctimony - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, Y, X, X

Spear Finishing Moves, Combos and Techniques
Horizontal Lance - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Proficient Attack - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Brutal Assault - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Double Spiral - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Chaotic Fire - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Cursed Nights - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Blind Shock - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y
Spirit Spoils - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y, X
Damnation - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y, X, X
Slip Blade - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y
Harpoon - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, Y
Brutal Reaver - Press: X, Y, Y, B
Vertical Lance - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Arc Rise Lance - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y
Fulguration - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Punishment - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X
Dark Prince - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X, X
Expiation - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X, X, X
Lance Bash - Press: B

Two-Handed Axe Moves, Combos and Techniques
Great Axe Cleave - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Cutting Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Maiming Blow - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X
Sacrilege - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Cleaver - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, X
Slaughter - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y
Lament - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, Y, Y
Reckless Surge - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Dark Zeal - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y, X
Ardent Force - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y, X, X
Tenderizer - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y
Unjust Crusade - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, X
Ventral Cut - Medium Attack – Press: X, Y, X, Y
Dissection - Light Attack – Press: X, Y, X, Y, Y
Odin’s Ire - Light Attack – Press: X, Y, X, Y, B
Vertical Great Axe - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Death Grip - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X
High Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X, Y
Iron Ram - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, Y, Y
Wild Abandon - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X, Y, Y, X
Heresy - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, Y, Y, X, X
Great Axe Thrust - Press: B

Double Mace Moves, Combos and Techniques
Double Mace Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Twin Mace Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Spiked Globes - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Hammer Fall - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, X, X
Avalanche - Light Attack – Press: X, X, X, X, X
Bone Sunder - Light Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Mauling Maces - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y, Y
Mutilator - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y
Short Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y, Y
Unified Force - Press: X, Y, B
Vertical Maces - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Two-Fold Maces - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Metal Hail - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Vile Hammers -Press: Y, Y, X, B
Clavicle Breaker - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Grisly Beating - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X
Profane Maul - Light Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y, X, X
Brutal Push - Light Attack – Press: B

Sword and Axe Moves, Combos and Techniques
Axe Blade - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Hunt Blow - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Steel Whirlwind - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
False Templar - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Iron Onslaught - Press: B
Axe Blade Cleave - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Knee Cutter - Light Attack – Press: Y, X
Dual Cut - Light Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Brutal Backhand - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y
Forced Strike - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Butcher’s Strike - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y

Sword and Mace Moves, Combos and Techniques
Blade Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Heavy Backhand - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Inverted Furrows - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Executor Strike - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Pole Attack - Press: B
Vertical Blade Bash - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Left Hook - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X
Baroque Murder - Medium Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Gut Desecrator - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
Twin Thrust - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Clean Cut - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Piercing Thrust - HEavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y

Axe and Mace Moves, Combos and Techniques
Bashing Axe - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Lethal Backhand - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Final Crusade - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Maiming Attack - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Shaft Knock - Press: B
Vertical Axe Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Double Attack - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Grim Redemption - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Triple Assault - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y

Mace and Shield Moves, Combos and Techniques
Shielded Mace - Heavy Attack – Press: X
Double Strike - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Scarlet Flower - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X, X
Dazing Strike - Press: X, X, B
Forehead Crusher - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y
Final Touch - Heavy Attack – Press: X, Y, X
Shaft Knock - Press: B
Thrusting Mace - Medium Attack – Press: Y
Vicious Swipe - Light Attack – Press: Y, X
Chin Splitter - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Crossed Rise - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y
Hammer Bash - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y

Spear and Shield Moves, Combos and Techniques
Shielded Lance - Medium Attack – Press: X
Spear Backhand - Heavy Attack – Press: X, X
Skewer - Medium Attack – Press: X, X, Y
Shield Shock - Press: X, X, B
Shield Strike - Press: B
Thrusting Lance - Heavy Attack – Press: Y
Pivot Strike - Light Attack – Press: Y, X
Feint Thrust - Light Attack – Press: Y, X, X
Double Thrust - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y
Tearing Blow - Medium Attack – Press: Y, Y, X
Dark Pilgrim - Press: Y, Y, X, B
Achilles Thrust - Heavy Attack – Press: Y, Y, Y
```

I think the weapons list is combined here with the combos and techniques, the weapons are pretty simple, two-handed sword, mace, one-handed sword...I tried doing multiple combos with different named maces and they work and have the same effectiveness with both names thus leading me to believe they are actually all the same, and not different as I listed above

Comment: While it claims to have a weapons list at the top, I've looked through that guide more then once and can't find it: Can you directly link it, or quote an example?

Comment: Updated answer and actually changed it after reading through that again

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking for the difference between a sword and a mace. I'm interested in the difference between two swords of the same type: ex a Barbarian sword and a Ceremonial Sword.